# Forwarding email as attachment (via apps-script) results in an empty attachment in destinatin email inbox

Tags: google-apps-script

This is as far as I got towards forwarding a tagged email as an attachment:

```
function myFunction() {
  var aLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("A-LABEL");
  aLabel.getThreads().forEach(function(thread) {
      thread.getMessages().forEach(function(msg) {
          var file = DriveApp.createFile('~myfile.txt', msg.getRawContent(), 'message/rfc822');
          var msg2 = GmailApp.createDraft("me@outlook.com", "Test", "See Attached", {attachments: [file]});
          msg2.send();
          DriveApp.removeFile(file);
      })
      thread.removeLabel(aLabel);
  })
}
```

The attachment in the receiving email system is empty, and I don't know why.

I'm trying to do this because regular `.forward()` changes the `From:` header. Well it does in apps-script, wheareas a filter-forward in the regular Gmail web UI does not, but I need to forward then delete which does not work.

Per suggestion of Guilherme M:

Commenting out the `DriveApp.removeFile(file)` line allows me to see the correct file in Drive, but remain confused as to why the resulting email doesn't have that attachment. Indeed it has `Content-Type: text/plain\nMIME-Version: 1.0` instead.

Comment: Did you check if the file is actually created? For example, if you remove line `DriveApp.removeFile(file);`, the file is there? A possible issue is that Gmail does not "attach" the file to the email, but instead makes a reference to it, so when you remove the file after sending the email, there is no attachment.

Comment: OK, so it is in Drive correctly, but is anemic when it has arrived at the destination email account. Specifically contents are `Content-Type: text/plain\\nMIME-Version: 1.0` which is odd because nowhere in my source is text/plain mentioned.  So your suggestion to comment out the Drive-file-delete was useful for chasing root cause, but timing of delete wasn't the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your situation. So for example, using a file which has already created, when you run this script, what mail will you get? ``var msg2 = GmailApp.createDraft("me@outlook.com", "Test", "See Attached", {attachments: [DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob()]}); msg2.send();`` ``id`` is the file ID of the file. In my environment, I got an email with the attachment file. I think that if you get the same one, it is required to check other parts of the script and others.

Answer (score 1):

Well it turns out that Outlook.com foes not like 'message/rfc822' attachments and neutralizes them to text/plain with no content. At least it does so for email from Gmail's apps-scripts facility. If I change the mime type to 'text/plain' then everything works as expected.

Comment: Gmail does a similar thing. If I check a bunch of emails and forward them as attachments, they won't be recognized by something like `GmailApp.getMessageById(messages[i].id).getAttachments()` however if you use `getPlainBody()` they do show up as part of the email body...

Comment: I know this is old, Paul, but I swear I had success (albeit accidentally, whilst trying to do something else) in saving and opening .eml files, which were fully HTML'd up ... I could be wrong, though. If you want me to root around, I can.